# WinJS / WinRT: detect corrupt image file

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winjs, storagefile

I'm building a Win8/WinJS app that loads pictures from the local pictures library. Everything is generally working fine for loading valid images and displaying them in a list view.

Now I need to detect corrupt images and disable parts of the app for those images.

For example, open a text file and enter some text in it. Save the file as .jpg, which is obviously not going to be a valid jpg image. My app still loads the file because of the .jpg name, but now I need to disable certain parts of the app because the image is corrupt.

Is there a way I can check to see if a given image that I've loaded is a valid image file? To check if it's corrupt or not?

I'm using standard WinRT / WinJS objects like StorageFile, Windows.Storage.Search related objects, etc, to load up my image list based on searches for file types.

I don't need to filter out corrupt images from the search results. I just need to be able to tell if an image is corrupt after someone selects it in a ListView.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution would be to check the image's `width` and `height` properties to determine whether it is valid or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the `contentType` property will return whatever the file extension is. The best way I can find it to look at the [image properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileproperties.imageproperties):

```
file.properties.getImagePropertiesAsync()
               .done(function(imageProps) {
                   if(imageProps.width === 0 && imageProps.height === 0) {
                       // I'm probably? likely? invalid.
                   });
```

Answer (score 0):

where SelectImagePlaceholder is an Image Control.. =)

> StorageFile file;
>
> ```
>         using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
>         {
>             try
>             {
>                 // Set the image source to the selected bitmap
>                 BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
>
>                 await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(fileStream);
>
>
>                 SelectImagePlaceholder.Source = bitmapImage;
>                 //SelectImagePlaceholder.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
>                 //SelectImagePlaceholder.Stretch = Stretch.None;
>                 this.SelectImagePlaceholder.DataContext = file;
>
>                 _curMedia = file;
>             }
>             catch (Exception ex)
>             {
>                 //code Handle the corrupted or invalid image
>             }
>         }
> ```